# jquery mobile trigger('create')

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a situation where I am generating a list from an AJAX call then switching to the page. When I do this, I get the following error:

```
  TypeError: d[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...-corner-all");this._addThumbClasses(h);this._addThumbClasses(e.find(".ui-link-in...
```

This is the code that does the ajax call and loads the DIV:

```
function handleGetReports(data) {
        $('#recentReportsText').html(data).trigger('create');
        $.mobile.changePage("#recentReportsPage", { changeHash:true});
}
function recentReports() {             
        $.post("getrecentreports.php",'',handleGetReports);
}
```

And this is the data that is returned by the ajax call:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete"><li data-role="list-divider">08/17 01:46pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Pending</p></li>
<li><a href="#">basic Company<br/>basic Username</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('4');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">08/16 06:50pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Complete</p></li>
<li><a href="javascript:popUp('reports/2012-08-16-3.pdf');">basic Info</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('3');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">08/16 06:44pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Complete</p></li>
<li><a href="javascript:popUp('reports/2012-08-16-2.pdf');">basic Number</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('2');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">07/16 06:38pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Pending</p></li>
<li><a href="#">basic Address</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('1');">Delete</a></li></ul>
```

This is the page that is displayed:

```
<div data-role="page" id="recentReportsPage" data-title="Recent Reports" data-needs-auth="true">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
<a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
<h1>Recent Reports</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">        
<div id="recentReportsText"></div>
</div><!-- /content --> 
</div><!-- /recent reports -->
```

If I leave off the .trigger('create') call no error is generated but the data displayed is unenhanced (ie: no listview). If I cut and paste the ajax returned HTML and put it directly in the page in the CONTENT section to be displayed it displays correctly in split-list format as I intended. Is this a jquery mobile bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

Edit: I am using minimized version of jquery. I have changed it to be unminimized and this is the error:

```
TypeError: parentPage[0] is undefined (line 5189 of jquery-mobile.1.1.1.js)
[Break On This Error]   

parentId = parentUrl || parentPage[ 0 ][ $.expando ],
```

Edit: BTW. This is only an error with the listview. I originally returned the results as a table without incident in all browsers.

Comment: If the returned ajax html is returned wrapped within a <div></div> block it mostly works (margins are weird). I can handle the margins with some CSS.

Comment: I take that back. It works in Firefox. Chrome and Safari still pitches an error.

Comment: If you don't use .trigger('create') and then use $('#ListViewsId').listview('refresh'); You should get your enhanced list.

Comment: Actually maybe it's because your calling create on an already existing element, and instead your should be doing something like:
data.appendTo( "#recentReportsText" ).trigger( "create" );

Comment: When I do the refresh call I get the error: Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Where are you defining the handleGetReports variable?

Comment: That's the name of the function that handles the callback for the returned data. It's in the second block above. I tried the appendTo and it didn't work any better.

Comment: if its the function shouldn't you be calling it with parenthesis and passing it the data parameter like so: `handleGetReports(data);`  ???

Comment: No, the format is just the function name. I use this same pattern in about 50 other places in the program without issue. This is the only problem I am having.

Comment: That's not it. I put an Alert(data) call in the handleGetReports() function and it displayed the correct data from the ajax call.

Comment: In that case, I guess jQuery does some magic and calls the function and passes the data to it, I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: Out of interest what is the returned HTML? If it's a multipage style jQuery Mobile site, could you not add the HTML for the list (just ul tags) into your code, and then just return only the li elements from your ajax call. That way you could use refresh instead of create.

Comment: The returned HTML is in the third block above. I tried just returning just the LI tags but I used CREATE. I will try now with refresh.

Comment: I tried with listview("refresh") and got the same uninitialized error. Also tried binding before pagechange and on pagecreate and none of that helped either.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source code you posted and created a working example.

The index.html contains both pages, the first page and the reports page. The test.html is the file which contains the reports data.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            function handleGetReports(d) {
                $('#recentReportsText').html(d).trigger('create');
            }

            $(function() { 
                $('#recentReportsPage').live("pagecreate", function() {
                    $.get('test.html', function(data) {
                        handleGetReports(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

        <div data-role="page" id="firstpage" class="type-home">
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#recentReportsPage">Click</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="recentReportsPage" data-title="Recent Reports" data-needs-auth="true">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <a href="#firstpage" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
                <h1>Recent Reports</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">        
                <div id="recentReportsText"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete"><li data-role="list-divider">08/17 01:46pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Pending</p></li>
<li><a href="#">basic Company<br/>basic Username</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('4');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">08/16 06:50pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Complete</p></li>
<li><a href="javascript:popUp('reports/2012-08-16-3.pdf');">basic Info</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('3');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">08/16 06:44pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Complete</p></li>
<li><a href="javascript:popUp('reports/2012-08-16-2.pdf');">basic Number</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('2');">Delete</a></li><li data-role="list-divider">07/16 06:38pm<p class="ui-li-aside">Pending</p></li>
<li><a href="#">basic Address</a><a href="javascript:deleteReport('1');">Delete</a></li></ul>
```

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.

BR,
Tolis

Comment: Thanks. But I had already tried that. I either get the original error, or it works the first time but when I use the back button then click the link to the page again I get unenhanced display of the page. The list to be displayed is generated dynamically by .php

Comment: This appears to be the solution:$(document).bind('pageinit, function() {  
        $('#recentReportsPage').live('pagecreate', function(){
                $.get('getrecentreports.php', function(data) {                 
                        handleGetReports(data);
                });
        });
});